# How can I create multiple objects from a for loop when they have different attritbutes?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I created a racing html 5 canvas and JS project that makes use of a colour API. I'm looking to clean up my code.
Is there a way I can change the code below into a for loop to save on the amount of code that has to be re-typed? I was thinking of a for loop but can't get my head around the idea of how I would chnage the values for the attributes on each iteration?

```
            c1 = new Car({ x: 0, y: 100, colour: "#" + json.colors[0].hex, windowsColour: "#" + json.colors[1].hex, number: 1 });
        c2 = new Car({ x: 0, y: 250, colour: "#" + json.colors[3].hex, windowsColour: "#" + json.colors[2].hex, number: 2, });
        c3 = new Car({ x: 0, y: 400, windowsColour: "#" + json.colors[4].hex, colour: "#" + json.colors[5].hex, number: 3, });
        c4 = new Car({ x: 0, y: 550, windowsColour: "#" + json.colors[6].hex, color: "#" + json.colors[7].hex, number: 4 });
```

Comment: @jaquarh hello there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use array **c[...]** and use a code like this

```
for (i=1; i<=4; i++) {
  c[i] = new Car({ x: 0, y: (i+1)*100, colour: "#" + json.colors[i].hex, windowsColour: "#" + json.colors[i+1].hex, number: (i+1) });
}
```

this will create c[1]...c[4]

Comment: Thank you:) Had to make a few tweaks to it with the y position but other than that worked great.. Also implemented it in other parts of my code :-)